# MSSQL Query Xml difference order

Tags: sql-server, xml, t-sql, xpath, xquery

My database need to store xml request when user send it, and the xml have 2 Communications elements, **WP** and **SA**, but they are not fixed (I mean position):

```
    <bms:OrgInfo>
      <bms:Communications>
        <bms:CommQualifier>WP</bms:CommQualifier>
        <bms:CommPhone>5555551212</bms:CommPhone>
      </bms:Communications>
      <bms:Communications>
        <bms:CommQualifier>SA</bms:CommQualifier>
        <bms:Address>
          <bms:Address1>1234 Test Avenue</bms:Address1>
          <bms:Address2>1234 Test Avenue</bms:Address2>
          <bms:City>Alamogordo</bms:City>
          <bms:StateProvince>NM</bms:StateProvince>
          <bms:PostalCode>88310</bms:PostalCode>
          <bms:CountryCode>US</bms:CountryCode>
        </bms:Address>
      </bms:Communications>
    </bms:OrgInfo>
```

Sometime **SA** element will be first.

How to query it without worry about poistion

Here is my current query, I used index to query it:

```
IF  EXISTS (SELECT * FROM sys.objects WHERE object_id = OBJECT_ID(N'[dbo].[XmlStore]') AND type in (N'U'))
DROP TABLE [dbo].[XmlStore]
GO

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[XmlStore](
    [XmlRequest] [xml] NULL
) ON [PRIMARY] TEXTIMAGE_ON [PRIMARY]

INSERT INTO [XmlStore]([XmlRequest]) VALUES('<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <bms:OrgInfo xmlns:bms="http://example.org">
      <bms:Communications>
        <bms:CommQualifier>WP</bms:CommQualifier>
      </bms:Communications>
      <bms:Communications>
        <bms:CommQualifier>SA</bms:CommQualifier>
      </bms:Communications>
      <bms:Communications>
        <bms:CommQualifier>EM</bms:CommQualifier>
      </bms:Communications>
    </bms:OrgInfo>')


;WITH xmlnamespaces ( 'http://example.org' AS bms )
Select
    t.XmlRequest.value('(/bms:OrgInfo/bms:Communications/bms:CommQualifier)[1]', 'nvarchar(100)') as WP_Value,
    t.XmlRequest.value('(/bms:OrgInfo/bms:Communications/bms:CommQualifier)[2]', 'nvarchar(100)') as SA_Value,
    t.XmlRequest.value('(/bms:OrgInfo/bms:Communications/bms:CommQualifier)[3]', 'nvarchar(100)') as EM_Value
FROM [XmlStore] AS t    

DROP TABLE [dbo].[XmlStore]
```

It would be a disaster if user re-order Communications elements!

Comment: can we see your script?

Comment: @maSTAShuFu: yeah, I edited the post to update the script

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can add an `XQuery predicate` like here

```
IF  EXISTS (SELECT * FROM sys.objects WHERE object_id = OBJECT_ID(N'[dbo].[XmlStore]') AND type in (N'U'))
DROP TABLE [dbo].[XmlStore]
GO

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[XmlStore](
    [XmlRequest] [xml] NULL
) ON [PRIMARY] TEXTIMAGE_ON [PRIMARY]

INSERT INTO [XmlStore]([XmlRequest]) VALUES('<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <bms:OrgInfo xmlns:bms="http://example.org">
      <bms:Communications>
        <bms:CommQualifier>WP</bms:CommQualifier>
      </bms:Communications>
      <bms:Communications>
        <bms:CommQualifier>SA</bms:CommQualifier>
      </bms:Communications>
      <bms:Communications>
        <bms:CommQualifier>EM</bms:CommQualifier>
      </bms:Communications>
    </bms:OrgInfo>')
```

--The XML once more, but in differing order

```
INSERT INTO [XmlStore]([XmlRequest]) VALUES('<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <bms:OrgInfo xmlns:bms="http://example.org">
      <bms:Communications>
        <bms:CommQualifier>SA</bms:CommQualifier>
      </bms:Communications>
      <bms:Communications>
        <bms:CommQualifier>EM</bms:CommQualifier>
      </bms:Communications>
      <bms:Communications>
        <bms:CommQualifier>WP</bms:CommQualifier>
      </bms:Communications>
    </bms:OrgInfo>')
```

--The query (all indexes are `[1]`)

```
;WITH xmlnamespaces ( 'http://example.org' AS bms )
Select
    t.XmlRequest.value('(/bms:OrgInfo/bms:Communications[bms:CommQualifier="WP"]/bms:CommQualifier)[1]', 'nvarchar(100)') as WP_Value,
    t.XmlRequest.value('(/bms:OrgInfo/bms:Communications[bms:CommQualifier="SA"]/bms:CommQualifier)[1]', 'nvarchar(100)') as SA_Value,
    t.XmlRequest.value('(/bms:OrgInfo/bms:Communications[bms:CommQualifier="EM"]/bms:CommQualifier)[1]', 'nvarchar(100)') as EM_Value
FROM [XmlStore] AS t    

DROP TABLE [dbo].[XmlStore]
```